# Importance of Kohn anomaly?

Tags: solid-state-physics

What is practical importance of Kohn anomaly for experimentalists and/or theorists?

Comment: Please specify the question. otherwise [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn_anomaly)

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what's wrong with this?  It's very specific and I believe person with experience should describe it in a few words. Besides, I can't find answer on wiki, nor elsewhere. If someone could point out where on wiki answer is, i would be grateful and apologize for recklessness.

Comment: "practical importance" is always debatable. I would not know where to start.

Did you try to google _Kohn effect OR anomaly +application_?
there is no theoretical explanation/basis for the effect as far as I could understand from [here](http://www.pro-physik.de/details/news/prophy10189news/news.html?laid=10189)
(downvote itn't mine)

Comment: Downvote is mine -- this question is too vague. If you understand at least something about Kohn anomaly, then ask a precise question. If you don't then first go learn about it somewhere or ask a question that makes it obvious that you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

The practical importance of a Kohn anomaly is that it is a direct evidence of electron phonon coupling in a metallic system.  This is used as evidence for electron-phonon coupling in BCS superconductors for example.  Further, a Kohn anomaly is a sharp change in a lattice vibration that can cause a lattice instabilities, which can result in structural phase transitions of a material in extreme cases.